# I would like to mount an external disk hard by usb on linux but i don't get it

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

When I make `fsdisk -l` get the following output

```
miguel@127:/var/log$ sudo fdisk -l

Disco /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 60801 cilindros, 976773168 sectores en total
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador del disco: 0x0000ee6f

Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968912895   484455424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968914942   976771071     3928065    5  Extendida
/dev/sda5       968914944   976771071     3928064   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I make ls /dev/sd*

```
miguel@127:/var/log$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb
```

When I typed the command dmesg get the following output below

```
miguel@127:/var/log$ dmesg | tail
[11880.520414] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[11880.520422] usb 1-2: Product: USB to Serial-ATA bridge
[11880.520428] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Sunplus Innovation Technology.
[11880.520433] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 012345678901
[11880.523640] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11880.524044] scsi host19: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[11881.525029] scsi 19:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SPIF301  USB2SATA Bridge  0108 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[11881.526133] sd 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[11881.535845] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[13057.878067] systemd-hostnamed[11009]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

I have tried to mount doing the following

```
miguel@127:/var/log$ sudo mount /dev/sdb
mount: no se puede encontrar /dev/sdb en /etc/fstab o /etc/mtab


miguel@127:/var/log$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb /mnt/usb/
Error opening '/dev/sdb': No se ha encontrado el medio
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': No se ha encontrado el medi
```

o

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

The device that is recognized as `/dev/sdb` obviously has no partitions. Create a partition table with `fdisk`, then format the partition(s) with `mkfs`, and you should be good to go.

If you're sure the device has already been partitioned and formatted then something else is wrong.

Comment: Or the filesystem isn't supported.

Comment: @alvits Then I would expect that at least the partition is shown by `fdisk -l`. It may be an unknown partition scheme (or unsupported by a custom built kernel), that's why I added the second paragraph, but I think that's rather unlikely as the OP seems to use the current Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But in this case the disk may not be partitioned. For example if it was formatted as a whole disk.

Comment: @alvits Just tried that with a pen drive; even then `fdisk -l` includes the drive in the list, but the partition listing stays empty: `Disk /dev/sdc: 4051 MB, 4051697664 bytes, 7913472 sectors ...`. The same with an empty partition table.

Comment: THanks for testing it. You reminded me that it should show in the disk list.